# Best method to generate file access tokens for multiple files while retaining flexibility for path renames

Tags: php, methods

I have a large set of files (more than 200) that are stored in different folders.
E.g.

```
File 1: folder_a/subfolder/file 1.txt
File 2: folder_a/subfolder23/file 2.txt
File 3: folder_b/subfolder56/file 1.txt
File 4: folder_c/subfolder78/file 56.txt
...
```

The folder names differ across the files.

I intend to show all these files in a list for my users to download individually, however I do not want to reveal the file path to my user.

My intention is to present the list of links, and each link containing a token.

```
<a href="access.php?token=sdj3123jjE8edasEOQE">File 1</a>
<a href="access.php?token=4634545232SDJEWsema">File 2</a>
<a href="access.php?token=LSOwldkOWMc3929sJKS">File 3</a>
<a href="access.php?token=TWjncwptn128ns92nsE">File 4</a>
...
```

What are some efficient methods that I can use to generate this token which can fufil the following requirements:

1. Short token
2. If I were to rename main "folder_x", the same token will still work.

My current approach is to hash all the file full paths, and when the user goes to `access.php`, it'll run through my whole directory of files to return a huge array of hashed paths. If there is a match, it will proceed to download. The problem with this, is that point number 2 is not fufiled.
Is my current method server intensive or bad?

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary to use `any complicated token` unless you wanted the `path_file` to be somehow `hard to guess`
(better: hard to be accessed by a user based on intuition : easy to try with an integer).

Could store the path_link into a table
 `FilePath(pk autonumber id, key varchar filepath)`
Record#`1,Path1`
Record#`2,Path2`

Link on html can be:
`<a href="access.php?token=1">File 1</a>`

Php file `access.php`

```
...
$sqlfilePath = "select filepath from FilePath where id=".$GET["token"]
run sql and generate the output
...
```

If want a hard to guess token just generate one based on predefined `collection/array` and  `random` ... or use `hashed name` ... up to you